How can I resolve "Parsing error: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in Ember.js?
My project uses ember-cli: 3.28.6, node:12.13.1
I am getting at least 100 of this error, in files that don't even have import statements, in files that were automatically generated by ember-cli, etc. I've tried adding "type":"module" to package.json (as I've seen advised in other places) and running npm install, to no avail.
Fortunately, it doesn't prevent the build from succeeding, but it swamps any useful information there might be in the build log output, so I would like for it to go away.
Anyone have any tips for this?
